# Can PLINQ generate two streams? An error stream and a data stream

Tags: c#, csv, plinq

I have a large (700MB+) CSV file that I am processing with PLINQ.  Here's the query:

```
var q = from r in ReadRow(src).AsParallel()
    where BoolParser.Parse(r[vacancyIdx])
    select r[apnIdx];
```

It generates a list of APNs for vacant properties if you are wondering.

My question is, **How can I extract a stream of "bad records" without doing 2 passes on the query/stream?**

Each line in the CSV file should contain colCount records.  I would like to enforce this by changing the where clause to "where r.Count == colCount && BoolParser.Parse(r[vacancyIdx])".

But, then any malformed input is going to silently disappear.

I need to capture any malformed lines in an error log and flag that n lines of input were not processed.

Currently I do this work in the ReadRow() function, but it seems like there ought to be a plinqy way to split a stream of data into 2 or more streams to be processed.

Anyone out there know how to do this?  If not, does anyone know how to get this suggestion added to the PLINQ new feature requests?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't make much sense, because PLINQ is based on a "pull" model (i.e. the consumer decides when to consume an item). Consider code like (using C# 7 tuple syntax for brevity):

```
var (good, bad) = ReadRow(src).AsParallel().Split(r => r.Count == colCount);

foreach (var item in bad)
{
    // do something
}

foreach (var item in good)
{
    // do something else
}
```

The implementation of `Split` has two options:

1. Block one stream when the current item belongs to the other stream.

   In the above example, this would cause deadlock as soon as the first good item would appear.
2. Cache the values of one stream while the other stream is being read.

   In the above example, assuming the vast majority of items are good, this would cause about 700 MB of your data to be kept in memory during the moment between the two `foreach` loops. So this is also undesirable.

So, I think your solution of doing it in `ReadRow` is okay.

Another option would be something like:

```
where CheckCount(r) && BoolParser.Parse(r[vacancyIdx])
```

Here, the `CheckCount` method reports any errors it finds and returns `false` for them. (If you do this, make sure to make the reporting thread-safe.)

---

If you still want to propose adding something like this to PLINQ, or just discuss the options, you can create an issue in [the corefx repository](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx).

Comment: I *really* appreciate your taking time to read and comment.  But, I do have a pull model.  When you say it "doesn't make much sense", I'm not sure what you mean.  Your response shows you understood what I was asking.  ;-)

The first solution you propose with the two distinct foreach loops looks like it will iterate over the dataset 2 times.  That is not going to work since each pass takes almost a minute, and future data sets may be even larger.

I'll code it up and test.  If it only passes over the data one time, that is a good solution.

Comment: Your second solution with the where clause is closer to what I'm looking for.  In fact, I'm going to steal your code, but rename CheckCount() to IsValid(r).  Thanks!  But, I'm still looing for a way with linq/plinq to create 2 (or more) streams with a single pass over the data.  I'll go to corefx now. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @MarkMoore In my first solution, I was trying to explain that if you iterate only once, you have to have one of the two fatal flaws. That's why it doesn't make sense.